# Дебаг SQL CLR функций в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, отладка, sqlclr

Можно ли SQL CLR проект подключить, как библиотеку к консольному приложению и дебажить ее там без деплоя на SQL-сервере?

Что-то попробовал такой хинт провернуть, так мне при запуске проекта предлагают законектится на сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Создания проекта для дебага SQL CLR описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180009/unable-to-debug-net-code-could-not-attach-to-process-sql-clr-remote-debugging)

1. Start Visual Studio 2012 with Elevated permissions of Administrator
2. Create SQL Server Project
3. In Project Settings/Debug Pane, Provide Connection String for Database Connection
4. From View Menu, Open SQL Server Object Explorer, If your connection string provided in Project doesn't create Instance of Server, then Recreate connection here...
5. Right click on Instance and Select Allow SQL CLR Debugging, it will show some warning accept everything but read warnings carefully.
6. Save Project and perform Rebuild, and test a Publish of project by Generated Publish Script.
7. Now Create a non-deployment script in project, put a break point press ALT+F5 to execute script with Debug option, when clr-procedure will occur and try to go inside it, it will ask for process to attach with windows, Please allow to Attach

Comment: Там обычная функция, которой передается значение и она что-то возвращает. Если проект создавать как DLL, а потом пометить нужными атрибутами, то он успешно дебажится в консоли, а потом можно залить на сервер. Попробовал создать SQL CLR проект и почему-то такого же хинта не получилось...

Comment: Прошу прощенья, я вас не так понял. Вы создаёте `Database Project`? Потом добавляете к нему `SQL CLR` или `SQL CLR C#`?

Comment: Да, да, да. И потом хочу задебажить в консоли.

Comment: Такой вариант пошагово описан на SO [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180009/unable-to-debug-net-code-could-not-attach-to-process-sql-clr-remote-debugging). Там вроде всё просто, но если буду проблемы с английским - обращайтесь. :)

Comment: Оформите в качестве ответа, я галку поставлю.

Comment: Поправил текущий ответ, дабы не плодить лишнего.

Comment: Ну и на русский хорошо бы.

Comment: Для этого надо ставить русскую VS. Потому как прямой перевод от перевода VS иногда удивительно отличается. :) Если у кого установлен - пусть добавит русскую версию инструкции, но английскую надо оставить, т.к. большинство пользуется всё же английской версией VS.

Comment: Не, интерфейс не нужно переводить. Я касательно описания действий.